# Сортировка, метод sort(fn)

Tags: javascript

Объясните почему получилось от меньшего к большему ?

```js
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
}

var arr = [ 1, 22, 15 ];

arr.sort(compareNumeric);

alert(arr);
```

Comment: Потому что так работает `sort`. А Вы что ожидали?

Comment: непонятно как идет сравнение

Comment: Сравнение идет так, как Вы написали его в `compareNumeric`.

Comment: return 1 || return -1 это индексы ?

Comment: нет, это индикатор `больше`/`меньше` для двух элементов массива, которые движок JS передает в Вашу функцию. Если `return -1;` (или другое число меньшее нуля), значит `а` меньше `b`.

Comment: понятно что ничего не понятно

Comment: Если в методе sort не указана функция идет сравнение как у строк (по буквам). Если нам нужно установить собственную сортировку нужна функция  с 2 параметрами (a, b)берем наш массив он выше будет сравнение 1 и 22; 22 и 15; 15 и 1; это все понятно

Comment: "это все понятно" - очень хорошо

Comment: 1 и 22; 22 и 15; 15 и 1 где первое число это а,второе б

Comment: и в зависимости как число больше будет  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;

Comment: возвратится 1 или -1

Comment: правильно так ведь ?

Comment: я не успеваю за Вашей мыслью

Comment: из массива метод sort берет от туда числа например 1 и 22 и засовывает в условия например if(a < b) return 1 вернет 1 а что дальше ?

Comment: что он делает с  1 я не могу понять ?

Comment: Я добавил текста в ответ. Если это не поможет, Вам придется искать кого-нибудь другого, кто сможет объяснить лучше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax

```js
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  console.log("comparing", a, b);
  return a - b;
}

var arr = [ 1, 22, 15 ];

arr.sort(compareNumeric);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

---

> что он делает с 1 я не могу понять ?

Метод `sort` сам "не знает", как сравнить два элемента массива. Но это знаем мы, и мы передаем это знание методу `sort` через параметр - функцию `compare`. Метод `sort` всегда стремится разместить элементы массива в порядке возрастания. Метод `sort` в своем алгоритме доходит до места, где ему надо сравнить два элемента массива. Метод `sort` вызывает функцию `compare` с этими двумя элементами и получает результат. Если этот результат меньше нуля - первый элемент (первый - в том порядке, в каком эти два элемента были переданы в функцию `compare`) меньше второго. Если результат больше нуля - первый элемент больше второго. Если результат - ноль, элементы считаются одинаковыми для целей текущей сортировки. Теперь метод `sort` знает, как соотносятся два элемента, которые ему надо было сравнить и может переставлять (или не переставлять) их для создания сортированного массива.

Answer (score 0):

Вы попробуйте сначала [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) почитать, прежде чем вопросы задавать

> Если функция сравнения `compareFunction` предоставлена, элементы массива сортируются в соответствии с её возвращаемым значением. Если сравниваются два элемента `a` и `b`, то:
>
> - Если `compareFunction(a, b)` меньше 0, сортировка поставит `a` по меньшему индексу, чем `b`, то есть, `a` идёт первым.
> - Если `compareFunction(a, b)` вернёт `0`, сортировка оставит `a` и `b` неизменными по отношению друг к другу, но отсортирует их по отношению ко всем другим элементам.
>     *Обратите внимание: стандарт ECMAscript не гарантирует данное поведение, и ему следуют не все браузеры (например, версии Mozilla по крайней мере, до 2003 года).*
> - Если `compareFunction(a, b)` больше `0`, сортировка поставит `b` по меньшему индексу, чем `a`.
> - Функция `compareFunction(a, b)` должна всегда возвращать одинаковое значение для определённой пары элементов `a` и `b`. Если будут возвращаться непоследовательные результаты, порядок сортировки будет не определён.